# What level of memory usage will trigger iOS's memory warning?

Tags: ios, swift, memory

My app may consume tens of MB of memory, and in rare cases it reaches 100MB. Do I need to worry about memory warnings and implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`? And how much time do I have to release memory? (I need to persist the data in memory to the hard drive.)

Suppose I target devices after iPhone 5.

Comment: There's a lot of variables that go into that formula (how many apps are running, iOS version, hardware specs, etc.), I don't think there's a hard point where a memory warning gets fired.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I just need a rough estimate for each device model. I don't have different devices to test with. Say, do I need to worry if my app consume 100MB on a iPhone 6?

Comment: @NeoWang It has 1 GB of RAM you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, here's the **discussion** of the method `didReceiveMemoryWarning` from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621409-didreceivememorywarning?language=objc#discussion).

**DISUCSSION**

> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is
>   called when the system determines that the amount of available memory
>   is low. You can override this method to release any additional memory
>   used by your view controller. If you do, your implementation of this
>   method must call the super implementation at some point.

As per this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3utwf8/whats_the_deal_with_didreceivememorywarning/) thread, even if you handle this event, your application can still be terminated to give space to the running applications. Also, often times all of the apps' `didReceiveMemoryWarning` on the device are invoked, not only yours.

I hope this answer is okay since this seems just a comment quoting the documentation :)